# Contradiction in the capacitor formula

Tags: capacitor

On the internet, it is frequently mentioned that for a fully discharged capacitor at the instance it is connected to a voltage source, it acts like a short circuit, thus drawing maximum current.

At the same time, we also know
\$i=c\frac{dv}{dt}\$.

During a short circuit, the voltage drop across the capacitor should be 0, so from the equation above, dv=0, current should be zero but it is drawing maximum current.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dv/dt is the derivative, you can't treat dv as a separate quantity from dt.

If we connect a voltage source to a capacitor, it is as if we are applying a step change in voltage to the capacitor: \$v(t) = u(t)\$. The derivative of the Heaviside step function is the Dirac delta function \$\frac{dv}{dt}=\delta(t)\$, so you indeed get a "delta" current spike.

That being said, the example is not physical and is purely a mathematical argument. In any real scenario, you will have some finite resistance between the voltage source and capacitor, for which you will obtain a first order differential equation describing the capacitor voltage.

Answer (score 5):

there's no contradiction. At the *moment of connecting*, the change in voltage is unbounded, and so, \$i\$ becomes unbounded as well. The thing is that the voltage source does *not* collapse, it's an ideal voltage source with the theoretical ability to supply infinite current.

Also, if you have a physical formula vs "mentioned on the internet", go with the formula. But here, the two agree.